# Why don't std::vector's elements need a default constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, default-constructor

And how can I write my own array class to not need a default constructor for *its* elements? Right now, when I do the new [] to allocate space, I need a default constructor.

std::vector does not.

How do they do this magic?

Comment: [std::vector and Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221610/stdvector-and-constructors)

Answer (score 33):

`std::vector` doesn't need the default constructor because it never uses it. Every time it needs to construct an element, it does it by using the *copy constructor*, because every time it has something to copy: either existing vector element or an element you yourself supplied for copying through a method's parameter (explicitly or implicitly, by relying on a *default argument*)

You can write a class like that in exactly the same way: every time you need to construct a new element in your array, require the user to supply an element for copying. In this case constructing that original element becomes user's responsibility.

Every time it appears as if `std::vector` "requires" a default constructor from you, it simply means that somewhere you relied on a default argument of some of the `vector`s methods, i.e. it was *you* who tried to default-construct an element, not the vector. The vector itself, again, will never try to default-construct elements.

In order to avoid the default constructor requirement during memory allocation, standard library allocates *raw uninitialized* memory block and then immediately copy-constructs new elements in that raw memory block (which is something `new[]` cannot do). This functionality is incapsulated in `std::allocator` class. You can use `std::allocator` in your code as well, meaning that the "magic" is immediately available to you too.

**Note:** The above applies to pre-C++11 version of C++ language specification. C++11 changed a lot of things. And these changes do create situations in which `std::vector` can use default constructors internally.

Also it might be worth noting that even the original C++98 specification allowed implementations to use *function overloading* instead of *default arguments* in order to implement the standard library interface. This means that formally it is possible to have a valid C++98 implementation of `std::vector` that uses default constructors *internally*.

Comment: on the other hand, they do use some magic that is very related: the std::allocator object.

Comment: `std::vector::emplace_back()` does call the default constructor. In general `emplace_back(Args...)` calls the constructor with arguments `Args...`

Comment: @Angelorf this answer was written before C++11 was released :) In fact C++11 changed the behaviour of `vector<X> x(5)` - now that is specified as calling the default constructor in-place 5 times, whereas in C++03 it meant that you default-construct one `X` and then the vector uses copy-construction 5 times, and your default is destroyed after.

Answer (score 12):

`std::vector` only requires the element to have a default constructor if you use it in a way which requires the default constructor.  So this code (stolen from a deleted answer) won't compile, because `X` does not have a default ctor:

```
#include <vector>

struct X
{
  X(int) {}
};

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<X> x(1); // vector of length 1, second argument defaults to X() !!
  return 0;
}
```

But if you write `main` like this instead:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::vector<X> x; // make empty vector
  x.push_back(X(1));
  return 0;
}
```

Then it works fine.

Comment: The first version will not compile, because `std::vector<X> x(1)` is a shorthand for `std::vector<X> x(1, X())`. It is in fact *you* who's implictly using the default constructor, not `vector`. Default arguments are evaluated "on your side".

Answer (score 8):

You could allocate a block of bytes, then use [placement `new`](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12582) to make new instance of `T` (your parametric type) via copy constructor (not default constructor of course) when new items are pushed to the vector's back.  This will not allow to to make "a vector of N default-initialized Ts" (which std::vector can make - which is why it **does** need T to have a default constructor for this purpose), but you could make vectors that start empty and can have Ts pushed onto them.

Comment: How do I allocate the space in the first place? malloc?

Comment: @anon: Take a look at how `vector` does it... it uses an allocator, for example `new_allocator`.  In my (old) Cygwin installation it works like this: `{ return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp))); }`  Or `malloc_allocator` does it this way: `pointer __ret = static_cast<_Tp*>(malloc(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));`

Answer (score 1):

For me the `std::vector` was requiring a default constructor for my class (say `T`) because I was calling `resize()` method of the `vector`, despite I was only calling the method to shrink the vector, but never to grow.