# Does std::vector call the swap function when growing? Always or only for some types?

Tags: c++, vector, swap

As far as I know I can use a vector of vectors (`std::vector< std::vector<int> >`) and this will be quite efficient, because internally the elements will not be copied, but swapped, which is much faster, because does not include copying of the memory buffers. Am I right?

When does `std::vector` exactly make use of the swap function? I can't find anything about it in the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf). Does it happen during buffer reallocation?

I did some tests to find it out, but I failed. The swap function for my custom data type isn't called at all.

**EDIT**: Here is my [test program](http://www.future-processing.com/~mczardybon/swaptest.cpp).

Comment: Could you provide the function definition for your swap function? It might not have been found via ADL/Koenig (argument-dependent lookup). Also, are the elements of your data type being swapped, or is it the vector of your elements that is swapped?

Comment: The code is added as an edit. I expected elements of the vector to be swapped somehow during resize to prevent deep copying. The STL headers are well obfuscated, but I think there is a path from std::vector::resize to some function calling swap.

Comment: I think this is a quality-of-implementation issue, and something you can't take advantage of portably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no links to back up this claims, but as far as I know, the STL implementation distributed with Microsoft C++ uses some internal non-standard magic annotations to mark `vector` (and other STL collections) as having-performant-swap so `vector<vector<>>` won't copy the inner vectors but swap them. Up to VC9 that is, in VC10 they'll switch to rvalue-references. I think you are not supposed to be able to mark your own classes the same way as there's no cross-compiler way to do it and your code will work only on the specific compiler version.

Edit: I had a quick look at the `<vector>` header in VC9 and found this:

```
    // vector implements a performant swap
template <class _Ty, class _Ax>
    class _Move_operation_category<vector<_Ty, _Ax> >
    {
    public:
        typedef _Swap_move_tag _Move_cat;
    };
```

Just for experiment, you could try to specialize this class for you own type, but as I said, this is STL version specific and it's going away in VC10

Answer (score 3):

std::vector traditionally copy-constructs elements in to the new memory when growing, then the old values are destroyed.  However, in the upcoming C++0x with rvalue references and move semantics, std::vector can move-construct elements in to the new memory.  This is far more efficient.  If you have a vector of strings or some other expensive-to-copy data, then move-constructing them essentially just copies the pointers to the held data and marks the source object as empty.  This is very cheap compared to copying and destroying, and effectively solves the costly vector reallocation problem for move-constructable types.  It's pretty much the swap optimisation you described, built in to the language.

Comment: I think move constructors are fine, but a lot can be done with swap itself. Why don't use default-constructor + swap + destructor instead of copy-constructor + destructor? The former does not require the costly deep coping.

Comment: Maybe because an efficient swap requires that an external function is specialized, and a move constructors integrate better with the language (move semantics, automatically binding to temporaries, perfect forwarding, etc).

vector could probably in theory ALWAYS use swap, but looking at the implementation of swap, it requires the class be default constructable.  vector doesn't require a default constructable class, only copy constructable (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376989/why-dont-stdvectors-elements-need-a-default-constructor).  I guess template magic deduces a default ctor.

Comment: Swapping is available for all types (`std::swap`), but it is more efficient only for types that specialize it. I suppose one could try to detect if a class defines `swap` member function, but there is still no guarantee that it will be more efficient for user-defined types than normal copying (could easily turn out to be a pessimization).

Comment: If no specialized `swap` is available, default `swap` will make 3 copies (to avoid one). Using this approach would impose an extra requirement to the type used in vectors: default constructible, which is against the standard. Even then, there are types for which default initialization and copy construction are equivalent performance-wise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think vector is permitted to use `swap` (found by ADL). It's not explicitly forbidden that I can find, but the requirements on the value type of vector are CopyConstructible and Assignable. Neither of those has `swap` as a valid operation (even an optional one), or any standard means to determine whether swap is overloaded or not. Possibly it could use `std::swap` (or a specialization, if one exists) where appropriate, because that has the same requirements on its parameters: CopyConstructible and Assignable (and specializations for UDTs of functions in namespace std must implement the defined behaviour of the generic template). That doesn't help with reallocation, though, because you'd have to construct some "empty" objects to swap with, and vector can't just decide of its own authority that its value type should be default constructible, when the standard doesn't require that.

I think it's reasonable to assume that if an operation isn't required for your type T, then it won't be performed, even if the compiler somehow psychically determines that it exists. In C++, just because something has the right functions defined to implement an interface doesn't mean it claims to implement the *semantics* of that interface. It's not until you pass it in a context which demands the semantics that you're claiming the behaviour of the functions is as expected for the interface. The standard doesn't demand a well-behaved `swap` for the value type of vector, so the implementation of vector can't assume that just because `swap` is defined, it's better than `operator=`.

That's just my interpretation of the intention of the spec, though, I can't find anything definitive either way.

23.2.4.3/4 gives a clue. When talking about `erase`, it says: "the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements". So vector is explicitly forbidden from using `swap` to shift forward the end of the vector after an erase: it *must* use `operator=`. I take that as a strong hint that the expectation of the authors is to use `operator=` for everything, otherwise they would not have been so careless as to forbid `swap` in the one case where it actually can be used without any need for a default constructor.

I also see Microsoft's point, described by you and jdv, that for containers of containers, there's a big gain to be had from swapping. As long as the "template magic" is such that it doesn't interfere with well-formed C++ programs, there's nothing wrong with an implementation providing a means for types to *tell* vector to swap.

For instance, possibly they have a type traits template with a double-underscore in the name. The effects of using that name are implementation-defined, so all bets are off. The C++ standard says nothing about how std::vector behaves in programs which specialise that template. Once you've used a reserved name in your program, the implementation can define vector to use `operator=`, `swap`, or `aubergine` for all the standard cares.

Answer (score 1):

What the standard says, I don't know exactly. The default in stl is copying, which is no fun if you edit vectors of vectors a lot.

However, the behavior you want is implemented in Visual C++ in their TR1 implementation, available as an update for VS2008 (TR1 is kind of a prelude to the C++ 0x standard). They buy their stl implementation from Dinkumware, like many other compiler vendors, so you can expect to see this appear on other compilers. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198.aspx.

If you use GCC this is of no use to you, but there's probably others around here that can tell you.

[Edit]
Reading on after editing, I found out that microsoft claims that the swap() optimization is their feature, not dinkimware's. At least that's how I read this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/01/08/q-a-on-our-tr1-implementation.aspx

Comment: I use Visual C++ 2008, compiler version 9.0.30729.1 SP and in the STL headers I can see that there is a function "_Uninit_move" being called somewhere from std::vector which has a comment "// use swap to instead of the copy constructor". This is why I think this compiler uses swap somehow in std::vector.

Comment: The last point is very interesting. Microsoft says: "In VC8, template magic is used to annotate containers (vector, deque, list, etc.) as having O(1) swaps, so containers-of-containers will swap them instead of making new copies and destroying the originals". So maybe what I am lacking is the annotation...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are asking what happens when you do the following:

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);
```

We can look at what libstdc++ does in this case as an [example](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01115_source.html#l00065).

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc> void vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(size_type __n) {
    if (__n > this->max_size())
        __throw_length_error(__N("vector::reserve"));
    if (this->capacity() >= __n)
        return;

    const size_type __old_size = size();
    pointer __tmp = _M_allocate_and_copy(__n,
        _GLIBCXX_MAKE_MOVE_ITERATOR(this->_M_impl._M_start),
        _GLIBCXX_MAKE_MOVE_ITERATOR(this->_M_impl._M_finish));
    std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish, _M_get_Tp_allocator());
    _M_deallocate(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage - this->_M_impl._M_start);
    this->_M_impl._M_start = __tmp;
    this->_M_impl._M_finish = __tmp + __old_size;
    this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
}
```

The important call here is [_M_allocate_and_copy](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01066_source.html#l00964)

```
template<typename _ForwardIterator> pointer _M_allocate_and_copy(size_type __n, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last) {
    pointer __result = this->_M_allocate(__n);
    std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__first, __last, __result, _M_get_Tp_allocator());
    return __result;
}
```

The important call here is [std::__uninitialized_copy_a](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01065_source.html#l00294)

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Allocator> _ForwardIterator __uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _ForwardIterator __result, _Allocator& __alloc) {
    _ForwardIterator __cur = __result;
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
        __alloc.construct(&*__cur, *__first);
    return __cur;
}
```

This is calling [construct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/construct/). As you can see, it is using the copy constructor.

```
void construct ( pointer p, const_reference val ) {
    new ((void*)p) T (val);
}
```

Therefore, when a reallocate happens, every element in the vector has the copy constructor called on it.

Comment: Except that the `_GLIBCXX_MAKE_MOVE_ITERATOR` thing changes that to a move constructor where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using swap function was overlooked when discussing C++ 0x standard.

In my opinion swap should be basic function known to the language level. It solves many rationals for adding rvalue references to the language.

Returning std::vector from function or assigning from temporary could use swap instead of copy. Containers could use it to optimize reallocation.

Alas. :(

Answer (score -2):

when you have a quite large vector and you want to release it, you can use swap function to swap it with an empty vector. This is a very efficient way to free memory space when using STL container.